# How to send keys to this element

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-webbrowser

I am using Python selenium chrome driver and i am stuck at filling out the csc and the year of the creditcard information field ( look at picture ). The credit card number and month works fine with this code:

```
        iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='js-iframe']")
        driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
        inputCC = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id("encryptedCardNumber")
        )
        inputCC.send_keys("1111222233334444")
        driver.switch_to.default_content()

        time.sleep(1)
        iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='js-iframe']")
        driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
        inputCC = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id("encryptedExpiryMonth")
        )
        inputCC.send_keys("08")
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

I tried to use the same for the csc and year with changing the id but it didnt work.
How to do it?

[image: Creditcard momth console insight]
[image: Creditcard year console insight]
[image: Creditcard csc console insight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't run your code, but I checked the HTML & your code. Here's what I think:

Because `//iframe[@class='js-iframe']` is a very general XPATH, you need to be more specific. In your site, you have many iframes with the same XPATH.

You can fill the Month because after calling `iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='js-iframe']")`, it gives you the FIRST iframe, which contains the Month.

Your code fails for Year/CSC because it uses the FIRST iframe (which contains Month) to locate Year & CSC.

---

To fix, you have 2 methods.

1. Write the correct XPATH.

- Month iframe: `//span[@data-cse="encryptedExpiryMonth"]/iframe`
- Year iframe: `//span[@data-cse="encryptedExpiryYear"]/iframe`
- CSC iframe: `//span[@data-cse="encryptedSecurityCode"]/iframe`

2. Find a list of iframes

```py
iframe_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='js-iframe']")
month_iframe = iframe_list[0]
year_iframe = iframe_list[1]
csc_iframe = iframe_list[2]
```